# Is every operation in try blocks atomic in Python?

Tags: python, multithreading, operating-system

The python docs say that the EAFP approach is preferred over the LBYL in multi threaded environments.

Is there a case in which multi threading fails?
I mean lets say that I want to read a file from a directory.
I could write something like this:

```
try:
    with open('Path/to/file', 'r') as content_file:
        content = content_file.read()
except ... :
```

Is there a way that the file could be removed while the program is reading it or something like this?

Comment: Could you please expand the acronyms to make the question more readable. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

> Is every operation in try blocks atomic in Python?

No, `try` doesn't add any form of atomicity. All it does is ensure the `except` or `finally` clause gets executed as appropriate.

> Is there a way that the file could be removed while the program is reading it or something like this?

Yes, you could lose access to the file (for example, if it resides on a network filesystem and network connectivity gets disrupted while you're reading). That said, this could happen irrespectively of whether your program is multithreaded, so threading doesn't really change things here.

Answer (score 2):

> Is every operation in try blocks atomic

No. The point is that "ask permission, then do thing" is definitely not atomic, while depending on the operation and the degree of atomicity required, "do thing" alone might be atomic.